# Adding multiple seekbar values together in a textview

Tags: java, android, textview, seekbar

Having trouble adding values together from multiple Seekbars. Trying to send the total to a total_view but it keeps showing up as 0. Im using two seekbars and the total should change depending on the movement on the bar so Im using onSeekChangeListener

```
public class CalculateGradeActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text_view;  //shows percentage
    TextView text_view2; //shows percentage

    TextView total_view; //show total from text_view and text_view2

    SeekBar seek_bar1;
    SeekBar seek_bar2;

    int exam_grade;
    int homework;

    int total;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculate_grade_view);
        seek_bar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarExam);
        seek_bar2 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarHomework);


        text_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageSeekbar1);
        text_view2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageSeekbar2);

        total_view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numeric_grade_id_output);


        seekbar();


    }



    public void seekbar() {


        int progress = seek_bar1.getProgress();
        text_view.setText(String.valueOf(progress));

        int progress2 = seek_bar2.getProgress();
        text_view2.setText(String.valueOf(progress2));


        total = exam_grade + homework;

        seek_bar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    text_view.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + "%");

                    exam_grade = progress;
                    total_view.setText(String.valueOf(total));

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            }
        );

        seek_bar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
            new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    text_view2.setText(String.valueOf(progress)+"%");
                    homework = progress;
                    total_view.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you change a value you have to recalculate the total before you display it.

```
seek_bar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(

        new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                text_view.setText(String.valueOf(progress) + "%");

                exam_grade = progress;
                total = exam_grade + homework;
                total_view.setText(String.valueOf(total));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        }
);

seek_bar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
        new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){


            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                text_view2.setText(String.valueOf(progress)+"%");
                homework = progress;
                total = exam_grade + homework;
                total_view.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


            }
        }
);
```

ja

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I know how to finish this.